# excel changes scientific notation of r dataframe when saved with write.csv

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, csv, rounding

I  have a dataframe with columns having values like:

```
 [1] 3.69e-01 4.84e-01 2.12e-01 3.50e-05 3.52e-27 4.53e-01 1.88e-06 1.16e-01 1.79e-10 1.58e-04 8.21e-02
[12] 2.15e-01 4.64e-01 6.23e-01 4.94e-05 4.08e-01 2.50e-02 8.94e-03 8.37e-06 6.29e-01 7.40e-09 7.24e-07
[23] 2.92e-13
```

when I seve them as .csv, and open it in excel they change into:

[image]

and when I use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables to generate table out of my .csv file, it also changes the formating of number.

How can I get .csv with exactly what I have in my dataframe?

Comment: notepad gives a different notation too. my goal is creating a table with values exactly like what I have in my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Excel and R (and Notepad) handle the display numbers differently, depending on a whole host of settings in both programs. If you're certain that you want the number itself to be fixed and always display the same way, your best option is probably converting it to a character vector because letters (should) always render the same. This is especially true if they're just going into a table.

Now, if you just convert them with something like `as.character()` you'll get the whole string (e.g. "0.00000000001231241") so your best best is actually the `formatC` function.

```
formatC(column, format = "e", digits = 2)
```

which should produce a character vector containing the values you have in the column but all formatted in scientific notation with exactly two digits.